# Can I create custom cells like these in swift 5 ios using messageKIt?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, messagekit

[image]

I am building a chat app and I am new to ios, I want to build custom cells like these using messageKIT, can anybody help me with any resource or code?

Comment: Do you know how to reuse TableViewCells using xib?

Comment: Yes, but can I use those with messageKit?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you want is **definitely** possible!

You may refer to [this](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/blob/master/Documentation/CUSTOM_CELLS.md) GitHub repo that contains a text document/guide on how to configure customs cells with `MessageKit` and examples.

An extract from the repo:

> **Note**: If you choose to use the `.custom` kind you are responsible for all of the cell's layout. You can design the cell in code or Interface Builder. Any `UICollectionViewCell` can be returned for custom cells which means any of the styling you provide from the `MessageDisplayDelegate` will not affect your custom cell, even if you subclass your cell from `MessageContentCell`.

Creating a custom cell involves four parts:

> 1. Build a cell in Interface Builder or code that inherits from `UICollectionViewCell`
> 2. Set the size of your cell. Subclass `MessageSizeCalculator` if you want your cell to have the default MessageKit layout design. Subclass `CellSizeCalculator` if you want to further customize your own cell design. The implementation of this class will allow your custom cell to automatically size itself within the `messagesCollectionView`.
> 3. Add your custom cell size to the collection view flow layout. Subclass `MessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout`, and use the custom message size calculator from step 2, above.
> 4. Register your custom cell and reference your custom collection view flow layout.